# writing a program to "roll a dice" needs to accept a number and roll number of times then output that many numbers of 1-6

Tags: javascript

Ex of what I want it to output: Dice.rollNDice(6) => [x,x,x,x,x,x] or 
 Dice.rollNDice(3) => [x,x,x]

I know the second part of my code is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it or what else to add to it. But I need to call rollDie and return an array representing the rolls

```js
rollDie: function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
    },

   
    rollNDice: function(n) {
        rollDie(var result = [];
            for (var i =0,i<=[/1-6/] ;i++)
            )
```

Comment: Your function is an object property, you need to call it as `Dice.rollDie()`

Comment: `rollDie()` doesn't take any arguments, why do you have all that code inside the `()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
I can tell you are new to this language. Why? Let me comment out all your errors you have made: (I fixed some of your indentation)

```
rollDie: function() { // Unexpected parenthesis: this is not how you define a
                      // function. Define a function by doing 'function rollDie()'
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1; // incorrect method of random
}, // remove comma

rollNDice: function(n) { // Same here: 'function rollNDice(n) {...}'
    rollDie(var result = []; // -.-
    for (var i =0,i<=[/1-6/] ;i++) // incorrect usage of for statement .-.
//           ^        ^
// bad formatting   ????? ._.
    ) // unexpected parenthesis ._.
// missing bracket from rollNDice ._.
```

I will show you the correct usage of the For Statement:

```
for (var i = 0; i > n i++) { // (var i; while i is greater than n; increment i)
    // do stuff
}
```

Now, I will show you how to get a random number from 1 through 6:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```

Almost there. Now let's change the rollDie function. Instead of rollDie: function()..., I'll change it to function rollDie(). The unexpected parenthesis is because of `foo: function()...`. It's formatted to be `function foo()`. But you must be new to this language.

```
function rollDie() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}

function rollNDice(n) {
    ...
}
```

Now, defining a variable inside a parameter is bad practice as far as I know. Or at least, I don't see it as often, other than for (var i...). Put result at the beginning: `var result = []`. Now for the For Statement.

```
for (var i = 0; i > n-1; i++) {
    result.push(rollDie()); // result.push(3) returns [3], and if 
}                           // result is [5, 4, 2], result.push(4)
return result               // makes it result[5, 4, 2, 4]
```

And it works! I'll show you:

```js
function rollDie() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}
function rollNDice(n) {
  var result = ["results:"];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      result.push(rollDie()); 
  }                          
  return result;               
}
console.log(rollNDice(4));
```

Output: `["result", 6, 1, 6, 5]`; it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong.

Since `rollDie` is a property, you have to call it as `Dice.rollDie()`. You don't put the `for` loop inside the argument list of a function, you call the function inside the for loop. And since you want to return an array of all the rolls, you need to build the array.

```
rollNDice: function(n) {
    var dice = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dice.push(Dice.rollDie());
    }
    return dice;
}
```